# Xpath not working when element contains xml:lang attribute

Tags: xpath, adobe-indesign

I am using an Xpath expression in Adobe Indesign to generate the list of elements used. I came to know, that if the element contains `"xml:lang"` attribute, then my Xpath expression does not work in Adobe Indesign.
For example in the below XML:

```
 <chapter>
    <section>
       <p xml:lang="en">This is sample para</p>
     </section>
 </chapter>
```

When I use the below Xpath expression to list

elements it does not generate any values.

```
//p
```

Is there any things needs to be done additionally

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882142/evaluate-xpath-expression-not-working-for-attribute-xmllang-in-indesign

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with Adobe Indesign but in terms of XPath the path `//p` should select all `p` element nodes in the input XML, whether they have an `xml:lang` attribute should not matter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct. When I use this is in Xpath Visualiser I can able to view the list of matches using the Xpath expression. Kindly let me know do I need to add any attribute/namespace in root element to make this Xpath expression to work in Adobe Indesign. Did xml:lang belongs to any additional attribute or something else?

Comment: I am sorry but as I am not familiar with Indesign and its XPath support I can't suggest any changes. It would be a bug or quirk in my view any way if the presence of that attribute requires a change to evaluate XPath expressions like `//p`. I have added a tag to your question so that indesign users might have a look. In terms of XPath the most likely reason that a path like `//p` does not select anything is the presence of default namespace declaration e.g. `xmlns="..."` on the root element of the XML so make sure this is not the case with the samples you feed to Indesign.