# evaluate XPath expression not working for attribute (xml:lang) in indesign

Tags: xml, applescript, adobe-indesign

I am using  Xpath expression in Adobe Indesign, to collect the list of elements. I am using the below code to generate it.

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5.5"
    set user interaction level of script preferences to never interact
    tell active document
        tell XML element 1
            set myElement to evaluate XPath expression using "//para"
        end tell
    end tell
    set user interaction level of script preferences to interact with all
end tell
```

The above code does not works fine if the element  contains "xml:lang" attribute.

Sample xml file:

```
<chapter>
<section>
<para xml:lang="en">This is sample para</para>
</section>
</chapter>
```

could you please let me know how i need to make my code to work for the above xml coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InDesign has several problems with namespaces. They better work when you use the "XML" object of ExtendScript, or if you don't use them at all (e.g. strip/replace them via an XSLT on import).

When I provided the namespace declaration for the xml namespace (even though redundant by the words of the standard), my InDesign CS6 found your para. E.g.

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
    tell XML element 1 of active document
        make XML attribute with properties {name:"xmlns:xml", value:"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}
    evaluate XPath expression using "//para"
    end tell
end tell
```